# Rubygems - update previous major version

Tags: rubygems

How do you update gems on a lower major version? Ex: rails 2.3.14. I wouldn't have know it existed if I didn't follow the project on github. Typically I find out about most gem update by running 'gem update', which obviously looks at the 3.X versions. Is there a way to have 'gem update' include lower major version of a gem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pessimistic version constraint](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16#page74).

```
gem 'library', '>= 2.2.0'
```

This is called an **OptimisticVersionConstraint**. They are optimistic that the incompatible changes introduced in version 3.0 will still work with their software. They have no assurance of this (most likely verion 3.0 wasn't written when they wrote the gem line). But they are willing to take the chance.

Some other clients of your library are not so hopeful. They fully expect that new interfaces will break their software, so they want to guard against accidently using the new interfaces. They use a **PessimisticVersionConstraint** that explicitly excludes your version 3.0.

```
gem 'library', '>= 2.2.0', '< 3.0'
```

Doing this is cumbersome, so RubyGems provides a pessimistic operator `~>` (read: approximately greater than). Using the pessimistic operator, we get:

```
gem 'library', '~> 2.2'
```

Notice that we only include 2 digits of the version. The operator will drop the final digit of a version, then increment the remaining final digit to get the upper limit version number. Therefore '~> 2.2' is equivalent to: ['>= 2.2', '< 3.0']. Had we said '~> 2.2.0', it would have been equivalent to: ['>= 2.2.0', '< 2.3.0']. The last digit specifies the level of granularity of version control. (Remember, you can alway supply an explicit upper limit if the pessimistic operator is too limited for you).